# Loading Content Into div - Resource Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web component which another  group wants to include in their web application.

They have asked that I render my page into theirs by rendering into a div. From my understanding they are going to provide an html page similar to this.

**TheirComponenetPopupWindow.html**

```
<html>
...
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
...
<div id='render_here'></div>
</html>
```

where `myscript.js` will be a script I will need to write.

Now, I have seen countless examples on stackoverflow where I can use `$(#render_here).load(..)` or `$.ajax(..,{..})`. However, all of these leave me with a serious problem. That all resources my page loads are now relative to the page I am being rendered into. This off course breaks my page as all of my scripts, images, and css files fail to load.

Is anyone aware of how I can use the methods mentioned above, or maybe a method I am unaware of, where I can render into a div and not break my resources?

Comment: iFrame sounds as solution. You'll call all resources as you're calling now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a iframe in the render_here div, and set the src of iframe with you page url.

Comment: This is inline with what I was thinking. My only concern is they are injecting  functions into the global space of their html page. I am just thinking out loud, but I could still access those internally as `window.parent.function`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need rewrite your code using absolute URLs if you want them to be portable to other locations such as a third party's site.

If you don't require interaction between your code and content on the third party page then an iframe would probably save you a lot of time and effort, but access to the third party's page would be prevented from within the iframe.